# Get csv file line terminator

Tags: python, string-formatting, dialect

In a python script, I need to detect the endline terminator of different csv files. These endline terminators could be: '\r' (mac), '\r\n' (windows), '\n' (unix).

I tried with:

```
dialecto = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(2048), delimiters=",;")
dialecto.lineterminator
```

But it doesn't work.

How I could do that?

**EDIT:**

Based on abarnert response:

```
def getLineterminator(file):
    with open(file, 'rU') as csvfile:
        csvfile.next()
    return csvfile.newlines
```

Comment: The `Sniffer` won't detect the `lineterminator` for the simple reason that (at least in 2.7 and 3.6) the `Reader` ignores `lineterminator` and treats any sequence of `\r` and `\n` characters as EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `csv` module to auto-detect line terminators this way. The `Sniffer` that you're using is designed to guess between CSV dialects for use by `csv.Reader`. But, as [the docs say](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator), `csv.Reader` actually ignores `lineterminator` and handles line endings interchangeably, so `Sniffer` doesn't have any reason to set it.

---

But really, a CSV file with a XXX line terminators is just a text file with XXX line terminators. The fact that it's CSV is irrelevant. Just `open` the file in text mode, read a line out of it, and check its `newlines` property:

```
next(file)
file.newlines
```

In Python 3, as long as you opened the file in text mode (don't use a `'b'` in the mode), this will work. In Python 2.x, you may need to specify universal newlines mode (don't use a `'b'`, and also *do* use a `'U'`). If you're writing code for both versions, you can use universal newlines mode, and it'll just be ignored in 3.x—but don't do that unless you need it, since it's deprecated as of 3.6 and may become an error one day.

Comment: Except that a CSV may contain quoted strings that themselves contain line terminators... and they might be a different sort of line terminator than that used to delimit end-of-row.  So if your first row contained a string like that, this method would detect the *wrong* kind of line terminator!